# always Session Expired in production server asp.net; but working fine in test environment

Tags: asp.net, iis

always Session Expired in production server asp.net; but working fine in test environment,
when i try to login my application i got session expired message, after 3 or 4 attempts i am able to login, but application works fine in test server

Comment: possible to give more details on your IIS session setting, between production and test server?

Comment: We need web.config and IIS settings, please

Comment: play spot the difference between your environments. Somewhere the session timeout value is likely different. It can exist in a few places. Plenty of material online already showing you how this works and where to configure it.

Answer (score 0):

add this line for your WebConfig file

```
 <system.web> 
<sessionState timeout="60"></sessionState>
 </system.web>
```